# Finder shows executable shell scripts as Unix binaries

Tags: finder, bash, script

I am writing and using many shell scripts (bash) on my mac. One issue has been bugging me for a while. When I look at the scripts in the Finder, they come up as "Unix Binaries". If I tag a file type (`.sh`) then the finder recognizes them as shell scripts.

[image]

If I tag a file type (`.sh`) then the finder recognizes it as shell script:

[image]

If I make the shell script file (without extension) non-executable (`chmod -x`) then the finder recognizes it as a text file. It looks like the finder thinks that any executable file without any extension is de-facto a Unix binary executable. I thought the finder was peeking at a file content to determine its nature ? Is there a way to control that ?

Answer (score 2):

This all seems correct.

Under Unix the only way any file is executable is if the executable bit is set in the file modes.

There is no such thing as a binary executable just executable and it does not matter what the file is script or compiled